Is there a way to use Spring Cloud Task without using/declaring Relational Database?
I tried to implement Spring Cloud Task in my application and from reading documentation I understood that it uses relational database to store the state of the Spring Cloud Task. But in the documentation there is also this sentence:

What does that sentence stating that it is possible to start developing Task without the database mean ? It states that the status of task is logged as part of repository updates.
Does this mean that I can use Spring Cloud Task without declaring the database ? If so, what needs to be done, because when I try to launch my application it asks for DataSource ?

Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75698573/spring-boot-cloud-task-without-springs-task-tables

Spring Cloud Task requires a database as stated in the documentation here. However you can run it with an in memory database like H2.
Feel free to follow the guide here on Spring's website as it shows how to setup Spring Cloud Task with H2.
